# How to auto-generate UML diagrams from Java code

Tags: uml, auto-generate

While trying to understand existing Java code, I am looking for a tool/application to auto-generate UML diagrams from the Java code. I am interested in the Class diagrams and Sequence diagrams in particular.

The community has discussed this topic in the past. The tools/applications suggested in the past are no more available, as I found out.

I have the following queries. Please clarify.

1. For the Class diagrams, I have found one app https://github.com/iluwatar/uml-reverse-mapper. It generates ".uml" files. Please suggest an application to open ".uml" files.
2. Please suggest an application for Sequence diagrams.